# Group locations on map based on distance

Tags: algorithm, dictionary, distribution

I've given the following problem. A set of locations (e.x. around 200 soccer clubs) is spread over a map. I want to group the locations based on their distance to each other. The result should be a list of groups (around 10 to 20) so that the distance each soccer club has to drive to visit all other clubs within their group is minimized.

I'm pretty sure an algorithm exists already. I probably only need the "official" name of this problem.

Can anyone please help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for [Data Clustering Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis#Algorithms). Since you have an idea of the number of clusters, a simple algorithm is [k-means clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to choose the maximum distance d at the outset (and then determine how few groups suffice to guarantee that no team needs to drive more than this distance to get to another team in their own group) then you can formulate the problem as a [graph colouring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring) problem: make a vertex for each team, and put an edge between two vertices whenever the distance between them *exceeds* d.  The solution to a graph colouring problem assigns a "colour" (just a label) to each vertex so that (a) no two vertices connected by an edge are assigned the same colour and (b) the number of distinct colours used is minimal.  (In other words, edges represent "conflicts", indicating that the two endpoints cannot belong to the same group.)  So here, each colour corresponds to a group, which is guaranteed to consist only of teams that are all <= d from each other, and the solution will try to minimise the total number of groups.  You might need to rerun with a few different values of d until you get a solution with acceptably few groups.

Note that this is an NP-hard problem, so it might take a long time to find an exact (minimal-group-count) solution.  There are many heuristics that are much quicker and still do a decent job, though.